# \tableofcontents and titlesec package interaction

Tags: latex

I use `titlesec` package, and `\tableofcontents` for TOC.

Problem: TOC header 'Contents' is on same line as the first section.

Beneath a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[tiny, compact]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[runin]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
  {\thesection.}
  {5pt}
  {}[.]

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction}
Test.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `runin` option for your custom header, you remove the automatic line break after it. As the toc is also a section, you see the same effect there.

If you want to only change the sections after the toc, you can move your redefinition after the toc:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\titleformat{\section}[runin]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
  {\thesection.}
  {5pt}
  {}[.]
  

\section{Introduction}
Test.

\section{Introduction}
Test.
\end{document}
```

[image]